# Generating a random unique token inside a trigger using a method from a separate class

Tags: before-trigger, unique-field

I'm using a random string generator code, which I found online. I need to know how I could access this code inside an Apex trigger from an apex class. I have pasted both my trigger and class, but I can't seem to make it work.

Trigger to generate a string every time an object is created:

```
trigger tokenGenerator on Certification__c(before insert) {
    for(Certification__c c: Trigger.new) {
        List<Certification__c> objects = [
        SELECT Id, Name
        FROM Certification__c];

        String x = token.createToken();

        for(Certification__c cer : objects){
            if(!cer.Name.contains(x) && cer.Name == 'A'){
                cer.Name = x;
            }
            else
                cer.Name = 'no token available';
        }
    }
}
```

APEX Class, random number generator class:

```
public class token {
    public static String createToken(){
        final String chars = 'BCDEFGH';
        String token = '';
        while (token.length() < 4) {
            Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
            token += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

What do I need to fix here, in order to get this trigger to work, note that I require a unique string.

Below I'm checking if the unique token created through the method is already inside the column(Name) of this table(certification), before assigning it to the text field. Am I doing this part correctly? Because when ever i try to generate a new value, it is not getting shown in this field. Before when I had all the code inside the trigger and not having a separate class for the token generator, it used to work and it will generate a random number, but it will not check for any duplicates.

```
for(Certification__c cer : objects){
    if(!cer.Name.contains(x) && cer.Name == 'A'){
        cer.Name = x;
        }
    else
       cer.Name = 'no token available';
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you need... The token class is working fine. It is generating a random string each time that it is called....

Comment: I have update my question

Comment: I am understanding that you would like a unique token for each record. But you are testing only the records that will be inserted in the transaction, not the records that are already in the database... Do you want a unique value for all records? If yes, there are another ways to do it.

Comment: yes, exactly. I want to check the unique tokens inside the database, before assigning a new token to this specific field. All objects created should have a unique token. Am I checking only the ones that will be inserted? How will you suggest for me to alter this. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand from question and comments, you need to create new certification with unique name which generates your Apex Class.
Here is the possible solution and some explanations:

1) You need to know what tokens are already used. For that I have created Set usedTokens.

2) You need to generate for each new certification new token. So **while** it is used, you should generate new one.

*P.S.: if you want to leave name as 'no token available' just remove while cycle and leave only check for availability.*

```
trigger tokenGenerator on Certification__c(before insert) {
    List<Certification__c> existingCertifications = new List<Certification__c>();
    existingCertifications = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Certification__c];

    Set<String> usedTokens = new Set<String>();
    for (Certification__c certification_i : existingCertifications) {
        usedTokens.add(certification_i.Name);
    }

    for (Certification__c certification_i : Trigger.NEW) {
        String tokenToCheck = token.createToken();

        while (usedTokens.contains(tokenToCheck)) {
            tokenToCheck = token.createToken(); // update for efficiency 
        }

        certification_i.Name = tokenToCheck;
        usedTokens.add(certification_i.Name); //update regarding the comments below
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, I will try this out and get back to you. Also, I already have tokens inside my system, that were entered manually, will this check them too? or just the ones I will enter in future. Thank you very much Mariia!!

Comment: Also, what happens when we exhaust all the available token? Will sf timeout?

Comment: @NivethKumar In this case it will be time out. However, you can always set the limit of iterations of trying to make a new token for the certification. Like: 

for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

}
  instead of while(){}

Comment: @PranayJaiswal This cannot happen because I get ALL records of certificaions and generate set from them as you can see from the code. However, you are partly right, because the set does not contain token that were generated during trigger usage, so every time we set certification_i.Name = tokenToCheck; we also need to do smth like this usedTokens.add(certification_i.Name);

Comment: In a given transaction its possible , the same token is generated twice. When you used once, you have to add it to the `usedTokens` set . Makes sense now?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal fixed, thank you for clarification

Comment: @NivethKumar Yes, it will check all the tokens that exist in database, even if you have entered them manually.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova the 'usedToken' is a temporary list which is created to hold the values created during a single instance of this trigger if I'm correct? please explain if I'm wrong

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova looks alright, using do - while makes more sense acc to me. +1

Comment: @NivethKumar First of all I am gathering all existing certifications in organization in the very beginning of the trigger. 

existingCertifications = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Certification__c];

Then I get all the token used before the trigger starts.

That means that every token in your org is checked and recorded before the trigger logic.

Then I add every new generated token into the usedTokens set not to add it once again for another record:

certification_i.Name = tokenToCheck;
        usedTokens.add(certification_i.Name); //update regarding the comments below

Comment: I understand now, I will try this out and get back. Thank you very much +rep

Comment: this solution could face some issues in the governor limits. If there are more than 50,000 certification for example.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: @mPeixoto This is just example solution. It is always possible to be scaled, for exmaple:

Integer count = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Certification__c];

Then run the for cycle with OFFSET  and LIMIT 50000 in SOQL query. 

Mine code is just the example of how to obtain the uniqueness of the token.

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova This works, thanks a lot Mariia!!!